# Format chart in Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I have the following issue when I try to change the format of the vertical Axis of a chart by using the setOption instruction in an Appscript. The format does not change. I have tested other setOption like setOption("vAxis", {title: "Total"}) and that works.

The code used the following :

```
function doGet(e) {
  const { spreadsheetId, chartId } = e.parameter;
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheets();
  const res = sheets.some(sheet => {
    const chart = sheet.getCharts().find(c => c.getChartId() == chartId && c.modify().getChartType() == Charts.ChartType.COLUMN);
    if (chart) {
      sheet.updateChart(chart.modify().setOption("vAxis", {format: "currency"}).build());
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(res ? "Done." : `Chart with chart ID ${chartId} and COLUMN chart `was not found.`);
}
```

Comment: Try `setOption("vAxes", {"0":{format: "currency"}}`

Comment: I have tried but no change. I have also put an  error check but If I put anything in the  format, I have no error.